# Find most matched string from pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have created a `pandas` dataframe object with all the `Files`, `FilePaths` and `FileDirectory` names which are in a specific folder. Now I am reading filenames from a json file and want to find the exact location of the files by searching 'FilePaths' or 'FileDirectory' from the dataframe/pickle(as it is much much faster to search).

What I am trying for example:

```
>> dcm_sure_full_path = '/Images/20150121100254179/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.229789272626/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712'
>> set(df[df['FileDirectory'].str.contains(os.path.basename(dcm_sure_full_path), regex=False)]['FileDirectory'])#.iloc[0]
```

This gives me 3 different paths, which means some part of the files matches with three different locations.

```
{'/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Images/20150121100254179/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.229789272626/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712',
 '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Working Storage/wilist_VascuCAP CT Development_SE/69930316/im0-1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712',
 '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Working Storage/wilist_WP A.2 Development_images_noTruth/69930316/im0-1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712'}
```

but you can clearly see I exactly needed the first one which matches the most with the desired path. 
 Now I tried to get the most matched one by the following code:

```
>> set(df[np.char.find(df['FileDirectory'].values.astype(str), dcm_sure_full_path) > -1]['FileDirectory'])#.iloc[rn])
```

or just change the `os.path.basename` in previous one:

```
set(df[df['FileDirectory'].str.contains((dcm_sure_full_path), regex=False)]['FileDirectory'])#.iloc[0]
```

which in result gives the desired path and discards two others.

```
{'/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Images/20150121100254179/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.229789272626/1.2.840.113845.13.4353.3528386102.230081008712'}
```

My ques is, are there better, smarter ways to do this sort of search and find with more accuracy so that I don't miss any file directory or so?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not simply use `in`? `[e for e in s if dcm in e][0]` where s is your set.

Comment: @Andreas I can get the files from the set. But are there better/smarter pythonic ways to fetch a file from a dataframe with path information? Is there anything wrong with the codes I am using to create the set?

Comment: I'm a little unclear. String contains would test if a substring exists in a value. Naturally `/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Images/2015...` contains the substring `/Images/2015...` so that returns a single value. (There is no conflict) However if you had two different strings [`/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/Images/2015...`, `/media/CAP_Exam_Data0/Images/2015...`] then you'd still end up with two results from `contains`, but I don't know that difflib is the correct way to determine which of those two paths is the most similar to the expected...

Comment: In the above sample of 2 strings checking `contains` on `media`, `CAP`, `Exam`, `_Da`, `mges` would all return the exact same values. It's unclear to me what the rules are for solving this problem. It's a bit difficult to determine similarity of file paths in this manner.

Comment: Got it. I would like to accept it as an answer if you haven't removed it. Thanks.